# R: Removing time series seasonality with made function

Tags: python, r, time-series, trend

I wrote the following function to remove the trend and seasonality of a dataset

```
# Create a differenced series
difference <- function(dataset, interval=1) {
  my_diff <- NULL
  
  for (i in seq(interval, length(dataset))) {
    value <- dataset[i] - dataset[i-interval]
    my_diff <- c(my_diff, value)
  }
  return(my_diff)
}

# Invert differences forecast
inverse_difference <- function(last_ob, value) {
  return(cumsum(value) + last_ob)
}

# REMOVING A TREND
# Defining a dataset with a linear trend
my_data <- seq(1,20)
my_data

# Difference the dataset
my_diff <- difference(my_data)
my_diff

# Invert the difference
inverted <- inverse_difference(my_data[1], my_diff)
inverted


# REMOVING SEASONALITY
# Defining a dataset with seasonality
my_time <- seq(0,20,0.1)
my_data <- (sin(my_time))

# Plotting seasonal data
plot(my_time, my_data, type="l")
plot(my_data, type="l")

# Difference the dataset
my_diff <- difference(my_data, 20)*2

# Line plot of the differenced seasonal dataset
plot(my_diff, type="l")

# Invert the difference
inverted <- inverse_difference(my_data[1], my_diff)
plot(inverted, type="l")
```

Removing the trend works fine. However, removing the seasonality does not and it's not clear to me why. I would expect a flat line when the data is differenced.

What's wrong and how could I fix it?

This code is "translated" from a Python code found at: https://machinelearningmastery.com/remove-trends-seasonality-difference-transform-python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case you don't realise it, you are reinventing the wheel here. R already has the functions `decompose` and `stl` to perform seasonal decomposition.

Using your own data:

```r
my_time <- seq(0,20,0.1)
my_data <- (sin(my_time))
```

We can perform seasonal decomposition by converting `my_data` into a time series (noting that its frequency will be `201/(20/(2*pi))`) then calling `stl` on the result:

```r
decomp <- stl(ts(my_data, frequency =  201/(20/(2*pi))), s.window = 25, 
              l.window = 64)
```

We can put this in a data frame with the original times to get some nice plots of the components:

```r
df <- cbind(time = my_time, as.data.frame(decomp$time.series))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(time, seasonal)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "Seasonal")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = trend, color = "Trend")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = remainder, color = "Remainder"))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm reading the documentation now and I'm a bit confused by the arguments. To make the time series stationary by removing both the trend and seasonality for monthly data which are the right parameters to use?

Comment: @Joehat you just need to create a time series from your data with a frequency of 12. In `stl`,  you could reasonably set `s.window` to 12 and not have any other parameters.